# Certbot: Issuing a certfiicate for internal IP address with my own PKI?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, pki, certbot

I am running my own ACME CA server that allows issuing of certificates to IP addresses. I have installed the root certificate into all the devices in my LAN. Let's say that I am running the server at `https://ca.internal/acme`. Now, I would like to issue a certificate for an internal IP address, say `10.0.0.2`. Let's also assume that I have a web server set up and working well. So now, I try to use the command `sudo certbot certonly -n --standalone -d 10.0.0.2 --server https://ca.internal/acme`, but it returns with an error saying that Let's Encrypt certificates do not support IP addresses. Is there a way (maybe by editing the Certbot config files) to resolve this problems and allow the issuing of certificates to an IP address? I've checked the [Certbot documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/) but have not found anything helpful there.

If it does turn out that what I'm asking is impossible with Certbot, are there any other ACME clients that support issuing a certificate to an IP address with an intermal CA?

Comment: Have you tried using a 3rd party ACME client?

Comment: What ACME CA implementation? The IP identifier extension RFC 8738 was published relatively recently. I cannot find if Boulder has made any progress. Although, uacme client claims support.

Comment: While iPAddress  cert may seem strange, the primary cited use case is DNS over HTTPS. Let's Encrypt cannot support RFC 1918 IPs, but presumably they will be a good way to issue certs for the IPv6 addreses of DoH servers.

Comment: Alternatively, set up a simple DNS server, such as `dnsmasq`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try uacme: https://github.com/ndilieto/uacme

It supports IP according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8738#section-3

Comment: or create a self signed one and create a wildcard certificate to match any address in the universe :)